# Regarding obtaining the version information of libraries that a Python project imports

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

Given Python project, we can know the libraries it uses by checking the "import" part. But how can we know the version of a given library?  For instance, the program has `import pandas pd`,  how can we know the version of `Pandas` it uses?

Comment: A Python project should be explicitly tellling you what external dependencies it requires and any version constraints in the `setup.py` or `setup.cfg` file (if it uses a setuptools-based distribution). Is this what you are asking?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import pandas as pd
print(pd.__version__)
```